# TextView and ListView in Relative Layout

Tags: android, listview, textview

I'm trying to setup a Relative Layout with a Toolbar on the top of the screen and a listView on the center. This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-48dp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        style="@style/HeaderBar"
        android:elevation="4dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how it looks like in the editor integrated in Android Studio:
[image]

I already checked and the list has one element, but when I try to open it this is what I see in the app:
[image: prova]

Can it be a problem related to the size of the TextView/ListView?

EDIT:
This is how it looks like after modifying the xml:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your layout the `ListView` uses all the space because it hasn't constraints like `android:layout_below="@id/textList"`.

You can use something like that:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      style="@style/HeaderBar"
      android:elevation="4dp"/>

  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="test"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/textList"/>   

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I updated the question with the result. The problem is that the textView and the ListView are separated

Comment: Solved removing android:layout_below="@id/textList"